# Alarm Manager problem in time setting

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to set an alarm at a particular date and time . iam getting my date and time with the webservice.i have parsed and splitted the date and time and used SimpleDateFormat and now i want to put this date and time in  [alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,dt, pendingIntent );] but my alarm doesnot work on the given time

```
       String str_date= hr+":"+min+":"+sec+" "+dat+"/"+mon+"/"+year;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
    ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);

    java.util.Date stringToDate = sdf.parse(str_date, position);
     dt = stringToDate.getDate();
```

Please help 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time you should pass to [Alarm.set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) is a `long` and `getDate`  (which is [deprecated](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate%28%29)) returns an int.

Try with `getTime()`

Comment: Still it it toast in the default time not to my parsed time

Comment: Try to swap the `time` and `date` like `date time` instead of `time date`

Comment: Since you are parsing the date yourself and you have got the different parts of date and time, you can use `Calendar` and use the `set` method with the date time parts. Then you can call `getTimeInMillis` and pass the result to the Alarm manager - More at  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 23);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 36);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        OnetimeAlarmReceiver(cal);

        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
        OnetimeAlarmReceiver(cal);

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager use time in millesecond unit at UTC time zone...
So time parsing have to take the timezone into account

So after SimpleDateFormat new instance you may set the UTC timezone

example :

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

then your parsing will be ok and compatible for the AlarmManager service.